# SQL Server 2008 R2 SSMS Default Login Username

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I recently created a few test accounts on my server and logged into them using SSMS.  When I start SSMS, my default login is now one of the test accounts.  How do I clear the login drop down list or reset my account as the default login username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the sqlstudio.bin file in the folder C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell.  This cleared the SSMS login info

CAUTION - this also removes your server/instance history, not just the default db accounts for the servers

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this blog post: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/11/05/sql-server-clear-drop-down-list-of-recent-connection-from-sql-server-management-studio/

Comment: Wasn't able to find the file that it referenced

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a way to quick connect to your favorite databases with saved credentials, then answer was given in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11204012/1249405